# Why would you want to not have the default instance name in a SQL server connection string?

Tags: sql-server

One of our customers does not want to put the default instance name "MSSQLSERVER" in the connection string. Unfortunately the dba has not replied to any of my emails inquiring what the problem is?

Any reasons why this would cause an issue?

JD

Comment: If it's the default instance then I didn't realise it *could* be referenced with a name. Was it installed as the default instance or was it installed as a named instance?

Comment: I'll turn the question around. What are your reasons for thinking it *should* be part of the connection string? [Microsoft's own documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191260.aspx) omits the default instance name.

Comment: Hi Joe, Well I do not think it needs to be there, and clearly without it the connection is still made. We can change the documentation to reflect this, it was more a question of why it has caused a problem from a dba point of view?

Comment: Hi Martin, SQL server was installed as the default instance. So we do not need to have it in the connection string.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You say "one of our customers does not want to put the default instance name ... in the connection string." You also comment that you "do not think it needs to be there", so aren't you and the customer in agreement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "problem" I would see is the confusion that would be caused when someone looks at the connection string and mistakenly thinks that they are using a named instance instead of the default.

This is one of the rare cases where I think you would actually make things clearer by omitting information.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply. I agree with others that it should not be there, I just wanted to know what the issues could be (i.e. whether it was a security problem or not).